# Can we copy data from Azure Analysis Services using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

I cannot find any connector related to this and wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: Is this [post](https://medium.com/ricoh-digital-services/process-azure-analysis-services-models-with-azure-data-factory-v2-d7c6288f352c) helpful for you? About using the Azure Analysis Services REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use [Azure Analysis Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/).

Answer (score 1):

By copying data from Azure analysis service , do you mean to pull the aggregated data from the OLAP system into a target store?
If yes, then there is no direct connector but you can pull the data based on a linked server concept via ADF v2.

We need to create a linked server between an IaaS/On Prem/SQL MI data instance and AAS Server :
[image]

In ADF, create a linked service connecting to the database instance and query the Azure analysis service through database instance via OpenQuery :

```
select * from openquery(AZUREAS, 
'evaluate SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
 ''Geography''[City],
 "My Measure", [My Measure]
)')
```

This is how you would be able to copy the AAS data from ADF into a destination :)

My Blog post for the same:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Nandan, Can you share more details how we can pull the aggregated data from Tabular models. i too looking for the same. Can we pass DAX queries and get the output as well? It would be beneficial for the whole forum.

Comment: @Vijay : I have updated the answer to fetch data via Linked server concept.

Comment: @Vijay: wanted to confirm, was this answer useful ?

Comment: Hey @Vijay
The below link would explain step by step for the same:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Can this be done for multi-dimensional cubes as well on SSAS?

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Function you can make a very easy c# script using

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient (to retrieve data) and
System.Data.SqlClient (to write data)

I suggest you using SqlBulkCopy to persist the retrieved DataTable for efficiency. but really depend if you need an upsert or you just want an insert.

Azure Function has a limited timeout and you pay for consumption, because of that it is not ideal for data with more than 10 min of retrieving + writing time. With ADF you may find an exploit to this limitation scheduling the process in more than one call.

The best case scenario for Azure Function: you have a polling that get the data from the AS and write data on your DB.

I wanted to share this solution because it could be cheaper than a linked server, especially if you have already an Azure Function premium plan.

There is also another way to retrieve data that include Sql Server integration Service but I think that if you had SSIS you would probably already know.