# How to store data from Azure Analysis services into Azure Datalake using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

How to store data from Azure Analysis services into Azure Datalake using Azure Data Factory?

I have two tables in Azure Analysis service and I need to copy and store those data into Azure Datalake using Azure Data Factory.

Could you please help me or share the reference url.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct connector for Azure analysis services in ADF but there are some ways via which you can copy the data :
1 such way is to create a linked server across a on prem/IaaS or SQL MI database instance and analysis services and get the data from the SQL instance through ADF.

[Can we copy data from Azure Analysis Services using Azure Data Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334966/can-we-copy-data-from-azure-analysis-services-using-azure-data-factory/65411964#65411964)

The above links explains it in details w.r.t the setup.

Below is my blog for reference :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Nandan - thanks for the swift response. But, I am getting below error.
**Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. This may happen if your data source only allows secured connections. If that's the case, please use a VNet integration runtime.**

Comment: Hey @LawranceAmburose,
Since you are trying to connect to on prem/IaaS/SQL MI which are within a Vnet, ADF cannot directly access the database .
So you need to set up a self hosted integration rum time and leverage that IR to connect to the database.

Linked server : https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/LinkedServer/SQL%20Linked%20Server%20to%20Azure%20Analysis%20Services.sql

IR : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

Comment: Sure, I will check and let you know if any issues

Comment: Hey @LawranceAmburose, did it work as expected? If yes, can you please mark it answer so that it would be beneficial for the community

Comment: Hi @Nandan - We have created the self-hosted integration but this facing the same issue. Could you please assist us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey @lawrance, can you please check the below features and reply back as that might help better debug : 1) test the linked server connection. You can test whether the linked server is properly configured or not by a test connection property   2) the SQL server on which you created the linked server , try accessing the analysis service from that server. 3) try accessing the analysis server from the VM in which you installed the integration run time 4) is the firewall enabled in Azure Analysis service?    Try accessing the analysis service from ssms or excel .just want to check accessibility

Comment: It seems Azure Analysis service is in different env.

Comment: @lawrance :
Blog post with step by step details :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory/